# Why is there a problem in plotting of certain EPSG codes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

It is mentioned that Geodetic coordinate system projections are not supported on cartopy, as I was trying to plot this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.epsg(3031))
ax.coastlines()
plt.show()
```

Output: nothing but a blank line

But in this case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.epsg(3857))
ax.coastlines()
plt.show()
```

Output: Correct Map

Maybe it is my lack of knowledge regarding EPSG's but I hope someone can shed light on this.

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is called creating a minimal, reproducible. example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @swatchai Thank you for the feedback, I have edited the question, I hope it is better now

Comment: For one thing, `epsg:3031` has details here: https://epsg.io/3031. Check it if it is the projection you intend to use.

Comment: @swatchai Indeed it is the epsg I want to test along many others. For example I put 3413 instead of 3031 and it produces a fine plot of relevant area but for 3031 it does not.